# Get a list of all the files in a directory (recursive)

Tags: file, groovy, directory-listing

I'm trying to get (not print, that's easy) the list of files in a directory and its sub directories.

I've tried:

```
def folder = "C:\\DevEnv\\Projects\\Generic";
def baseDir = new File(folder);
files = baseDir.listFiles();
```

I only get the directories. I've also tried:

```
def files = [];

def processFileClosure = {
        println "working on ${it.canonicalPath}: "
        files.add (it.canonicalPath);
    }

baseDir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES, processFileClosure);
```

But "files" is not recognized in the scope of the closure.

How do I get the list?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []

def dir = new File("path_to_parent_dir")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list << file
}
```

Afterwards the list variable contains all files (java.io.File) of the given directory and its subdirectories:

```
list.each {
  println it.path
}
```

Comment: By default, groovy imports java.io but not groovy.io so to use FileType you must have explicitly import it.

Comment: For using FileType, make sure you use the right groovy version: "the class groovy.io.FileType was introduced in Groovy version 1.7.1." see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317373/unable-to-resolve-class-groovy-io-filetype-error

Comment: This  was displaying the folder names along with its path.
Eg: `/tmp/directory1`
How to get the `directory1` alone in the output

Comment: weird..this gives the root path even if i preface it with a `.` It goes `/./path`

Comment: How can I list all folders on directory ?

Comment: does `file ->  list << file` works similar to `list.add(it)` or is there a difference?

Comment: @R.Sluiter there is no difference

Comment: This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934110/how-to-get-files-in-jenkins-pipeline-file by placing the code in the `script` section of a shared library.

Comment: there is no type File in jenkins goovy

Answer (score 30):

Newer versions of Groovy (1.7.2+) offer a JDK extension to more easily traverse over files in a directory, for example:

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
def dir = new File(".");
def files = [];
dir.traverse(type: FILES, maxDepth: 0) { files.add(it) };
```

See also [1] for more examples.

[1] http://mrhaki.blogspot.nl/2010/04/groovy-goodness-traversing-directory.html

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me in Gradle / Groovy for `build.gradle` for an Android project, without having to import `groovy.io.FileType` (NOTE: Does not recurse subdirectories, but when I found this solution I no longer cared about recursion, so you may not either):

```
FileCollection proGuardFileCollection = files { file('./proguard').listFiles() }
proGuardFileCollection.each {
    println "Proguard file located and processed: " + it
}
```

Comment: although this probably does not recurse through subdirectories.  However: worked for my purposes for separating out proguard files and importing them all at once :)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question "all the files in a directory (recursive)". It will only list the current directory and is misleading in the context.

Comment: `fileTree` recurses.

Comment: `FileTree` does not include directories (not treating them as files).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I came up with for a gradle build script:

```
task doLast {
    ext.FindFile = { list, curPath ->
        def files = file(curPath).listFiles().sort()

        files.each {  File file ->

            if (file.isFile()) {
                list << file
            }
            else {
                list << file  // If you want the directories in the list

                list = FindFile( list, file.path) 
            }
        }
        return list
    }

    def list = []
    def theFile = FindFile(list, "${project.projectDir}")

    list.each {
        println it.path
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the list was taken from the IDEA above.
The problem with the above scripts is that they require to import groovy.io.FileType.FILES. gradle scripts don't like that.
So I just made a method to look for the files that calls itself when a directory is found.

Answer (score 2):

With Kotlin Gradle script one can do it like this:

```
// ...
val yamls = layout.files({
    file("src/main/resources/mixcr_presets").walk()
        .filter { it.extension == "yaml" }
        .toList()
})
// ...
```