# "unable to resolve class groovy.io.FileType" error

Tags: groovy

What's causing this?

```
$ echo -e "import groovy.io.FileType;\nprintln 'hello'" > foo.groovy
$ groovy foo.groovy 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, /work/fun/BitMarket/database/foo.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class groovy.io.FileType
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import groovy.io.FileType;
   ^

1 error
```

My Groovy version is 1.6.4. Was this class added in a later version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [GroovyDocs](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.7.1/groovy-1.7.1-javadoc.jar!/index.html) the class `groovy.io.FileType` was introduced in Groovy version 1.7.1. The [GroovyDocs for version 1.6.4](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.6.4/groovy-1.6.4-javadoc.jar!/index.html) don't indicate that this class exists. I guess you have to upgrade your Groovy JDK.