# How to run all rulesets from a folder using PMD Ant in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, pmd

I am trying to run `PMD` from `Ant` in `Eclipse` when I build the project.

This is my build.xml file:

```
<taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask"/>

<target name="check_pmd">
    <pmd rulesetfiles="C:\Users\Nikolay\ProjectName\lib\rulesets\java\basic.xml">
        <formatter type="html" toFile="pmd_report.html" toConsole="true"/>
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\Nikolay\ProjectName\src">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </pmd>
</target>
```

It works well for `basic.xml`, but I want to run for all rulesets in `java` folder (It has around 20 rulesets) So I have tried:

```
<pmd rulesetfiles="C:\Users\Nikolay\ProjectName\lib\rulesets\java\*.xml">
<pmd rulesetfiles="C:\Users\Nikolay\ProjectName\lib\rulesets\java\*">
```

But both of them fail when I try to run. **Is there a way to specify folder, not a single file without specifying list of files manually?**

**For future readers to configure Ant PMD under Eclipse:**

- Download `pmd-bin.zip` from official website
- Unpack `pmd.jar`, `jaxen.jar` and `asm.jar`
- Add jars above to Window - Preferences - Ant - Runtime - Ant Home Entries - Add External JARs
- Unpack `rulesets` folder
- Reference location of ruleset from `<pmd rulesetfiles=...>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(expanding answer from coolfan for ant task)

The documentation of PMD rulesetfiles says it is [comma separated list of files.](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.6/ant-task.html)

> **rulesetfiles**  A comma delimited list of ruleset files
>   ('rulesets/basic.xml,rulesets/design.xml'). If you write your own
>   ruleset files, you can put them on the classpath and plug them in
>   here. Yes, unless the ruleset nested element is used

Ant provides a way to convert fileset into such a format. [The task is pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html)

here is an example from website

```
<fileset dir="${src.dir}" id="src.files">
      <include name="**/*.java"/>
 </fileset>

 <pathconvert pathsep="," property="javafiles" refid="src.files"/>
```

Comment: Thank for answer and sorry for not being able to use it this week. Don't you mind if I give bounty to coolcfan?

Comment: @ Nikolay Kuznetsov : No problem. As you see, I expanded answer from him :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the param doesn't support wildcard, as the [document](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.2/ant-task.html) suggests.

A quick look over its source code also supports my guess, see [RuleSetReferenceId.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/code/ci/6426deca6b8ec7068cb2f844539412c31d2908ce/tree/pmd/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/RuleSetReferenceId.java), line 194.

So, it takes a property which contains a "list" using `,` as delimiter, like:

```
"rule1,rule2,rule3,path-to-rule-file4"
```

The workaround could be scanning the directory, list all the rule-xml files, and build a property in the comma-delimited format and then pass it to `<pmd>` task.

Unfortunately, I don't know any ant task which can do this. So you may have to write some code.

I can come up with two ways:

1. write a ant task; there are many Q&As about this for Java, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008043/list-all-files-from-directories-and-subdirectories-in-java).
2. write groovy inside a `<groovy>` task; also many [Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953965/groovy-get-a-list-of-all-the-files-in-a-directory-recursive).

---

EDIT:

Jayan suggests `<pathconvert>` task, which should be the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I give you bounty and accept answer to Jayan. I hope it is okay for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the pmd library jar there is an all-java.xml where all the rule sets have been included.
Try to use the following:

```
<pmd rulesetfiles="rulesets/internal/all-java.xml">
```