# Write all files in a directory to .gsp page

Tags: grails

Lets say I have a gsp page that I want to load all the scripts in a particular folder:

```
<html>
<head>
{each file in $path}
<asset:javascript src="file" />
</head>
</html>
```

assuming `$path` is a directory path. Most templating languages have a way to do this so I'm sure Grails can accomplish it. But I'm not sure how to make it happen. My end goal is this:
ndex

```
<html>
<head>
<asset:javascript src="js/util.js" />
<asset:javascript src="js/util2.js" />
<asset:javascript src="js/index.js" />
</head>
</html>
```

Please help.

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953965/groovy-get-a-list-of-all-the-files-in-a-directory-recursive) help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <g:each var="file" in="${(new File(path)).listFiles()*.path}">
            <asset:javascript src="${file}" />
        </g:each>
    </head>
</html>
```

The GSP [g:each](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/each.html) tag is how iteration is performed in Grails when using GSP. The *in* attribute is used to specify the `Iterable` to iterate through. In this case it's the expression:

```
(new File(path)).listFiles()*.path
```

The expression means:

1. `new File(path)` - Create a Java `File` object to represent the directory *path*.
2. `.listFiles()` - Returns a list of all files and directories (excluding sub-directories) each represented by `File` objects.
3. `*.path` - A [spread operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator) expression which returns a list of file path `String`s, effectively converting the `File` objects into `String`s. It's the equivalent of `.collect { it.path }`.