# How to get files in jenkins pipeline file?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to get all files name with some pattern from work-space through jenkins pipeline script.

Get list of pjs files from my work-space and store to array

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [findFiles](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/):

```
files = findFiles(glob: '**/.pjs')
```

> Find files in the current working directory. The step returns an array
>   of file info objects.

These ***file info objects*** have `name` as a property, so you can easily get the name of the files as below:

eg. `files[0].name`

*Note:*

*Make sure that you in the the correct directory (workspace) using [pwd()](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-pwd-code-determine-current-directory) and [dir()](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-dir-code-change-current-directory).*

Comment: This step requires the pipeline utility steps plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps which in turn has several dependencies including Jenkins 2.73.2. Sad to discover this as I have no control over the version of Jenkins we use at work.

Comment: After some messing around, I found out that you can get the file content with `readFile(files[0].toString())`. `files[0].name` just gives you the filename without path.

Comment: @Nick, I'm curious if you found a way to do this without pipeline-utility-steps. I'm in the same boat at the moment. Maybe I'll just make an os call with a sh/bat step.

Comment: Where can I find the full list of properties of these "file info objects"?

Comment: @funkybro a file info object is of type [FileWrapper](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/0b912dac3870b880d354dcbe0d21cfff4b08ff93/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/fs/FileWrapper.java). Put `import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.fs.FileWrapper` at the top of your Jenkinsfile to use `FileWrapper` in your code.